# Big Excel: Makro doesn't run, Excel dosen't respond

Tags: vba, excel, runtime

I have a Problem. I have Data from a survey and I'm trying to fill a database with it. It worked fine with the 8 test data sets. Now I have ~1000 data sets and it doesn't run and excel stops responding. The database has 18720 row with 61 columns where each cell has to be calculated. The code for it is :

```
Sub DataBase()

'Set my tables
    Dim Answers As ListObject
    Dim Table As ListObject
    Set Answers = Worksheets("quantitativ").ListObjects("DataQuant")
    Set Table = Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Tabelle7")

'Set my Ranges for filters (Organizational level, Location, Function...)

    Set OrgRange = Answers.ListColumns(19).Range
    Set LocRange = Answers.ListColumns(20).Range
    Set FuncRange = Answers.ListColumns(22).Range
    Set TrainRange = Answers.ListColumns(23).Range
    Set InvRange = Answers.ListColumns(25).Range

'Set Ranges for Answers to Questions (Scale)
Set Q1 = Answers.ListColumns(26).Range
Set Q2 = Answers.ListColumns(27).Range
Set Q3 = Answers.ListColumns(28).Range
Set Q4 = Answers.ListColumns(29).Range
Set Q5 = Answers.ListColumns(30).Range
Set Q6 = Answers.ListColumns(31).Range
Set Q7 = Answers.ListColumns(32).Range
Set Q8 = Answers.ListColumns(33).Range
Set Q9 = Answers.ListColumns(34).Range
Set Q10 = Answers.ListColumns(35).Range

Set Q11 = Answers.ListColumns(36).Range
Set Q12 = Answers.ListColumns(37).Range
Set Q13 = Answers.ListColumns(38).Range
Set Q14 = Answers.ListColumns(39).Range
Set Q15 = Answers.ListColumns(40).Range
Set Q16 = Answers.ListColumns(41).Range
Set Q17 = Answers.ListColumns(42).Range
Set Q18 = Answers.ListColumns(43).Range
Set Q19 = Answers.ListColumns(44).Range
Set Q20 = Answers.ListColumns(45).Range

Set Q21 = Answers.ListColumns(46).Range
Set Q22 = Answers.ListColumns(47).Range
Set Q23 = Answers.ListColumns(48).Range
Set Q24 = Answers.ListColumns(49).Range
Set Q25 = Answers.ListColumns(50).Range
Set Q26 = Answers.ListColumns(51).Range
Set Q27 = Answers.ListColumns(52).Range
Set Q28 = Answers.ListColumns(53).Range
Set Q29 = Answers.ListColumns(54).Range
Set Q30 = Answers.ListColumns(55).Range

Set Q31 = Answers.ListColumns(56).Range
Set Q32 = Answers.ListColumns(57).Range
Set Q33 = Answers.ListColumns(58).Range
Set Q34 = Answers.ListColumns(59).Range
'Spalte 60 Textantwort
Set Q35 = Answers.ListColumns(61).Range
Set Q36 = Answers.ListColumns(62).Range
Set Q37 = Answers.ListColumns(63).Range
Set Q38 = Answers.ListColumns(64).Range
Set Q39 = Answers.ListColumns(65).Range
'Spalte 66 Textantwort
Set Q40 = Answers.ListColumns(67).Range

Set Q41 = Answers.ListColumns(68).Range
Set Q42 = Answers.ListColumns(69).Range
Set Q43 = Answers.ListColumns(70).Range
'Spalte 71 Textantwort
Set Q44 = Answers.ListColumns(72).Range
Set Q45 = Answers.ListColumns(73).Range
Set Q46 = Answers.ListColumns(74).Range
'Spalte 75 Textantwort
Set Q47 = Answers.ListColumns(76).Range
Set Q48 = Answers.ListColumns(77).Range
Set Q49 = Answers.ListColumns(78).Range
Set Q50 = Answers.ListColumns(79).Range

Set Q51 = Answers.ListColumns(80).Range
Set Q52 = Answers.ListColumns(81).Range
'Spalte 82 Textantwort
Set Q53 = Answers.ListColumns(83).Range
Set Q54 = Answers.ListColumns(84).Range
Set Q55 = Answers.ListColumns(85).Range
Set Q56 = Answers.ListColumns(86).Range
'Spalte 87 Textantwort
Set Q57 = Answers.ListColumns(88).Range
Set Q58 = Answers.ListColumns(89).Range
Set Q59 = Answers.ListColumns(90).Range
Set Q60 = Answers.ListColumns(91).Range

Set Q61 = Answers.ListColumns(92).Range
'Spalte 93 Sinnlos? (Textantwort)
'Spalte 94 Textantwort

'Row variables for For-Loop
Dim r As Long

    With Worksheets("Database")
        'Gehe alle Zeilen der Tabelle durch
        For r = 5 To Table.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 4

            'Q1
            .Cells(r, 9).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q1, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q2
            .Cells(r, 10).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q2, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q3
            .Cells(r, 11).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q3, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q4
            .Cells(r, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q4, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q5
            .Cells(r, 13).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q5, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q6
            .Cells(r, 14).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q6, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q7
            .Cells(r, 15).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q7, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q8
            .Cells(r, 16).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q8, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q9
            .Cells(r, 17).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q9, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

           'Q10
            .Cells(r, 18).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q10, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

           'Q11
            .Cells(r, 19).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q11, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q12
            .Cells(r, 20).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q12, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q13
            .Cells(r, 21).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q13, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q14
            .Cells(r, 22).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q14, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q15
            .Cells(r, 23).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q15, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q16
            .Cells(r, 24).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q16, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q17
            .Cells(r, 25).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q17, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q18
            .Cells(r, 26).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q18, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q19
            .Cells(r, 27).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q19, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

           'Q20
            .Cells(r, 28).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q20, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

           'Q21
            .Cells(r, 29).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q21, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q22
            .Cells(r, 30).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q22, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q23
            .Cells(r, 31).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q23, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q24
            .Cells(r, 32).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q24, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q25
            .Cells(r, 33).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q25, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q26
            .Cells(r, 34).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q26, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q27
            .Cells(r, 35).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q27, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q28
            .Cells(r, 36).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q28, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q29
            .Cells(r, 37).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q29, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q30
            .Cells(r, 38).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q30, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q31
            .Cells(r, 39).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q31, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q32
            .Cells(r, 40).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q32, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q33
            .Cells(r, 41).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q33, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q34
            .Cells(r, 42).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q34, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q35
            .Cells(r, 43).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q35, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q36
            .Cells(r, 44).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q36, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q37
            .Cells(r, 45).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q37, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q38
            .Cells(r, 46).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q38, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q39
            .Cells(r, 47).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q39, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

           'Q40
            .Cells(r, 48).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q40, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

'Q41
            .Cells(r, 49).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q41, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q42
            .Cells(r, 50).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q42, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q43
            .Cells(r, 51).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q43, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q44
            .Cells(r, 52).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q44, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q45
            .Cells(r, 53).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q45, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q46
            .Cells(r, 54).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q46, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q47
            .Cells(r, 55).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q47, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q48
            .Cells(r, 56).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q48, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q49
            .Cells(r, 57).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q49, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

           'Q50
            .Cells(r, 58).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q50, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

'Q51
            .Cells(r, 59).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q51, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q52
            .Cells(r, 60).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q52, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q53
            .Cells(r, 61).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q53, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q54
            .Cells(r, 62).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q54, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q55
            .Cells(r, 63).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q55, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q56
            .Cells(r, 64).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q56, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q57
            .Cells(r, 65).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q57, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q58
            .Cells(r, 66).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q58, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

            'Q59
            .Cells(r, 67).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q59, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

           'Q60
            .Cells(r, 68).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q60, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

'Q61
            .Cells(r, 69).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Q61, _
        .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
        .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))

        Next r

    End With


End Sub
```

Is there any way to improve the code to make it run or does any of you guys have another idea ho to solve it?
Thanks alot.

Comment: The non-responding part could just be Excel dedicating resources to calculate the values. Given that there're 18720 rows, you probably won't have immediate output. Maybe try turning off screen updating and calculations to speed things up.

Comment: Probably actually Excel doesn't respond **because** the macro runs and it takes a long time. While it runs Excel doen't respond. Try to use arrays or loops to reduce your code and use functions instead of repeating code. • It's quite unclear what you are trying to do here. So if you can explain in your question ([edit]) what you are actually trying to do there might be a better approach. Screenshots might help to explain.

Comment: First of all try to set the calculation to manual: `Application.Calculation = xlManual`. And turn off the screen updating: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. And at the end of the code turn both back `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

Comment: I have 61 Questions which are answed an a scale 1 to 5. About 1000 people completed the survey. They all have certain attributes, like their level, their location, their training and so on. The data output from the survey is in the form that the columns are the attributes of the people who answer the questions followed by the questions. Rows are the different data sets (people). The Database has to include every possible combination of these attributes, so that I can evaluate the data properly. These combinations add up to the 18720 rows mentioned. I hope that clears it up.

Comment: @Zsmaster I included it, but it doesn't help.

Comment: What you actually do in a single line within the loop is to make Excel go through all the 18K rows, make 6 comparisions in each row to decide whether to increase the counter. That makes 18K*18K*6*61 comparisions. So it simply overloads Excels. It will work but do not expect quick response. You can track the progress by using `Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & CStr(r)` within the loop. I suggest employing @Zsmaster's comments and testing the sub with the first 20 rows. If it is ok, you will only need patience.

Comment: Is it really necessary to `Set` 61  `Range` objects? That's a lot of memory allocation. 

Taking a quick glance at your code, it looks like a lot of it could be simplified with a `for`loop

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to reduce to code like this:

I used an array to store the column numbers of the questions, so we can loop through easily. Also I added a status bar update so you can see which row is getting processed. It will still take its time as there are many iterations.

I also added a timer so you will see the average time of processing one row and the estimated time to process all rows. 
But note that the status bar update adds additional (even minimal) load.

```
Public Sub DataBase()
    'Set my tables
    Dim Answers As ListObject
    Dim Table As ListObject
    Set Answers = Worksheets("quantitativ").ListObjects("DataQuant")
    Set Table = Worksheets("Database").ListObjects("Tabelle7")

    'Set my Ranges for filters (Organizational level, Location, Function...)
    Set OrgRange = Answers.ListColumns(19).Range
    Set LocRange = Answers.ListColumns(20).Range
    Set FuncRange = Answers.ListColumns(22).Range
    Set TrainRange = Answers.ListColumns(23).Range
    Set InvRange = Answers.ListColumns(25).Range

    'Set Ranges for Answers to Questions (Scale)
    Dim QuestionColumns As Variant
    QuestionColumns = Array(26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, _
                            26, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, _
                            46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, _
                            56, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, _
                            68, 69, 70, 72, 73, 74, 76, 77, 78, 79, _
                            80, 81, 83, 84, 85, 86, 88, 89, 90, 91, _
                            92)


    Dim QuestionColumn As Variant
    Dim c As Long

    Dim rStart As Long: rStart = 5
    Dim rEnd As Long: rEnd = Table.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 4

    Dim StartTime As Double
    StartTime = Timer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    With Worksheets("Database")
        Dim r As Long
        For r = rStart To rEnd 'Gehe alle Zeilen der Tabelle durch
            'update statusbar
            Application.StatusBar = "Processing Row " & CStr(r) & _
                                    ", Runtime: " & Format(Timer - StartTime, "0.00s") & _
                                    ", Time per row: " & Format((Timer - StartTime) / (r - rStart + 1), "0.00s") & _
                                    ", Estimated time: " & Format((Timer - StartTime) / (r - rStart + 1) * (rEnd - rStart), "0.00s") & _ 
                                    ", Time left: " & Format(((Timer - StartTime) / (r - rStart + 1) * (rEnd - rStart)) - (Timer - StartTime), "0.00s")
            DoEvents

            c = 9
            For Each QuestionColumn In QuestionColumns                    
                .Cells(r, c).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Answers.ListColumns(CLng(QuestionColumn)).Range, _
                                     .Cells(r, 8), OrgRange, .Cells(r, 1), LocRange, .Cells(r, 2), FuncRange, _
                                     .Cells(r, 4), InvRange, .Cells(r, 7), TrainRange, .Cells(r, 5))
                c = c + 1
            Next QuestionColumn
        Next r
    End With

    Application.StatusBar = "Done."

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```